# How to maintain the user session without data loss and without refreshing the page in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, session, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have implemented an application:

**Technology used:** -- Angular, Mvc, WebApi.

How I have calculated the session in the application means?

When user login into the app, Set the logout time , Before 3 minutes set the warning message to the user.In the warning message, there is an proceed button and close button.

Proceed button is for continue the user to another 15 minutes. Cancel button is for cancel the warning message.

**Implementation**

Here how I capture the Session
**Angular run block:**

```
 myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $cacheFactory, $interval, $timeout, $state) {

    // here I have implemented the logic 

    // set the 15 minutes to the logout.

 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, $rootScope, $state, $location) {
        lastDigestRun = Date.now();


if(current url != login url)

{

// show the warning message to the user ,in 2 minutes have remaining logout.

}

//In the warning message,there is an ok button for maintating the session to another 15 minutes,This is the code

 $('#ok').click(function () {
            location.reload();
        })

    });
}
```

**What's the problem over here is:**

**Implementation technology.**

1. I have using angular ui router navigation between the pages.     if
   any navigation between the pages, comes to run block and state
   -router   and reload the session for the user as active. working as expected.

**Problem for mine.**

1. if any of the nested views , there are 100 textboxes , user is enter
   the data,after 13 minutes he gets the warning alert.
   user not made any changes, gets the warning message.
2. At that time,  notification comes and click the Proceed button ,the page gets refreshed , and
   the data gets losses.

**Need to Handle :**

In the OK button,need to handle with out dataloss for the ui-router views. Here reload cause data loss in the textbox.

3. In that Scenario, need to handle the Data loss. How to handle that any one could suggest is it possible, is there any solution?

Comment: @Walfrat expecting your solution.

Comment: @sahir why refresh, just reset the timeout

Comment: @farhan-latheef Again I have to reset the function what they define initilally right  .. Thanks man